# How can I pass an array from VBA to R using a shell

Tags: r, arrays, vba, shell

I'm trying to pass an array from Excel VBA to R using a shell. It works with a single argument, but my code crashes in VBA if I try to pass an array to R.

My VBA code:

```
Sub test()

 Dim oShell As Object
 Dim oExec As Object
 Dim oOutput As Object
 Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
 Dim style As Integer: style = 1
 Dim errorCode As Integer
 Dim path As String
 Dim var1
 Dim var2

 Set oShell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 var1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Offerte").Range("B9").Value
 var2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Offerte").Range("B10:B11").Value

 path = """C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.1\bin\x64\rscript.exe""" & """S:\Test2.R """ & " " & var1 & " " & var2

 errorCode = oShell.Run(path, style, waitTillComplete)

End Sub
```

---

My R code:

```
options(echo=TRUE)

args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)

var1<-as.numeric(args[1])

var2 <- args[2]
```

It works if I only use var 1, but with var 2 I get the following message: 
type mismatch

Does anyone know if it's possible to send an array from Excel to R (without using a csv file or a for loop)?

Comment: There is no "Array to String" default casting in VBA, so the `... & var2` won't work. You can use something like [Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function) to build the String.

Comment: How would you pass an arry if you had to type the command line yourself?

Comment: Thanks Vincent G. Actually the data I would like to pass from excel vba to R are arrays of both numbers and text. I'm a bit familiar with R and VBA, but not with the shells for interaction. Is it possible to just send data through shells from VBA to R (and should I change something in the command line)?  And should I always send it as string (so also convert numbers)? I was looking into this, but I can only find examples online with single parameters or examples with csv files in between. I seems a bit odd that it's not possible to just send an array of number through a shell.